# Update Field Properties

Tags: apex, sobject, update, properties

I want to Update Field properties

```
 Schema.SObjectField field = fieldMap.get(fieldName);

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = field.getDescribe();



    labelMap.put(fieldDescribe.getLabel(), fieldDescribe.getInlineHelpText());
       String   colors = fieldDescribe.getInlineHelpText();
    NRT_NatureOfRequestType__c nt =new  NRT_NatureOfRequestType__c();
   String paint='paint';
       String color = paint+colors;
       nt.CareType__c.InlineHelpText= color;
       Upsert nt;
     system.debug('colos '+nt); 

    }
   }
  }
```

**NRT_NatureOfRequestType__c**()---> is My object

**CareType__c**----> is my field

I want Update "Help Text" properties under **CareType__c** field

The Error is

> **Invalid foreign key relationship: NRT_NatureOfRequestType__c.CareType__c**

Is it possible is Salesforce?
Or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating metadata information is not possible in apex yet.

If the functionality is critical for business, you can try using [Apex Wrapper for the Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) by [Andrew Fawcett](https://github.com/afawcett).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new (paid) admin tool which allows bulk update of all object & field meta properties, including help, description, formula fields, etc. from a provided Excel list - so something has changed to now allow this?

[Bulk Object Field Creator](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000qDqqEAE)